# Wait result from intent user

Tags: android

my code :

```
public void run() {
    while (!done){
        try {
            this.mListMessagesResponse = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ("to:" + recipient).execute().getMessages();
            done = true;
        } catch(UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

            //wait result
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

i want wait the result from my user to start again my loop.
i tried with wait but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you explain more what you want to do , because your startActivityForResult will execute only if you have an UserRecoverableAuthIOException.

Comment: I'm getting a message list, and if i haven't the permission from my user (Gmail api) an intent which is askinf permission is started, and i want wait this permission to get my message list.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a while loop to get the result from an Activity. There is already a build-in function to do that. It's `onActivityResult`

From the docs:

Start the Activity

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
...
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

Use `onActivityResult` to get the result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

See here for more [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: ty for this answer, but this doesn't really help me, i've already looked the documentation. but i want just wait during the intent, and when the intent is finished, continue my code.

Comment: @Clément That makes no sense whatsoever. Your whole while loop is exception based which should not be done in the first place at all. Use the `onActivityResult` to get your list `service.users()...`

Comment: i agree that's a bit strange, but it's just a user permission, wich is throw only 1 times when you download the app, that's why i only do it in the exception.

Comment: @Clément: "i want just wait during the intent, and when the intent is finished, continue my code" -- that is not possible, sorry. `startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous by nature; nothing short of creating your own version of Android will change that.